# difference between memory measured by statm and by top

Tags: linux, memory

The amount of memory used by my program reported by top is more than twice the amount reported in /proc/[pid]/statm.  What explains this difference?

Answer (score 2):

From the "man" page:

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html

```
/proc/[pid]/statm
Provides information about memory usage, measured in pages.  
The columns are:

        size       (1) total program size
                   (same as VmSize in /proc/[pid]/status)
        resident   (2) resident set size
                   (inaccurate; same as VmRSS in /proc/[pid]/status)
        shared     (3) number of resident shared pages
                   (i.e., backed by a file)
                   (inaccurate; same as RssFile+RssShmem in
                   /proc/[pid]/status)
        text       (4) text (code)
        lib        (5) library (unused since Linux 2.6; always 0)
        data       (6) data + stack
        dt         (7) dirty pages (unused since Linux 2.6; always 0)

Some of these values are inaccurate because of a kernel-
internal scalability optimization.  If accurate values are
required, use /proc/[pid]/smaps or
/proc/[pid]/smaps_rollup instead, which are much slower
but provide accurate, detailed information.
```

ALSO: *VMsize* is the "address space" that the process has in use: the number of available adresses. These addresses do not have to have any physical memory attached to them. Attached physical memory is the RSS figure.

Q: So what specific values did you have questions about?

---

Please see my comments below, and please refer to these links:

- [man top](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html)
- [man proc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)
- [Increase of Virtual Memory without increase of VMSize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13309395/421195)

Short answer:

- *RES* in top (*RSS* is ps), this is the sum of memory that is mapped to physical pages of memory.
- *VMsize* is the "address space" that the process has in use: the number of available adresses.
- "VMSize" addresses do not (necessarily) have any physical memory attached to them.
- Attached physical memory ("Resident memory") is the RSS figure.

It would also be helpful to see your actual values from top, /proc/nnn/stat and from ps.

---

Here's a great article (one of many):

> [Process Memory Management in Linux -
> Baeldung.com](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/process-memory-management)
>
> - **VSZ Memory**
>
> VSZ is short for Virtual Memory Size. It’s the total amount of
> memory a process may hypothetically access.
>
> It accounts for the size of the binary itself, any linked libraries,
> and any stack or heap allocations.
>
> When a process is started, VSZ memory becomes RSS memory...
>
> - **RSS Memory**
>
> As opposed to VSZ, RSS, also short for Resident Set Size, is a measurement that shows how much RAM has been allocated to a
> process during its execution
>
> But, it isn’t actually an accurate measurement for RAM usage for a
> process since it doesn’t take into account libraries already loaded in
> memory...
>
> Because RSS shows the whole memory output, even for information that
> has already been preloaded, if we add up everything in the processes
> list, we’d get more memory than the total memory allocated.

Comment: Sorry for being incomplete.  I was referring to the "size" column of statm versus the RES column of top.

Comment: BASIC PROBLEM: it sounds like you're comparing apples to oranges.  "/proc/xxx/statm" reports multiple different statistics (including "size", which refers to "VMSize"); "top" reports different (related, but different) "memory" statistics.  The different numbers refer to different things.  SUGGESTIONS: 1) Look  here: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html, here: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html and here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13309395/421195. 2) [Edit] your post, copy/paste the top and statm values, 3) Specify which values you're unclear about.

Comment: I don't know if your question is answered or not.  If not, please see my latest update, pertaining to this article: https://www.baeldung.com/linux/process-memory-management